# Javascript string interpolation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, flickr, galleria

I have a Galleria (galleria.io) that works when the code looks like this:

```
Galleria.run('.galleria', {
  flickr: 'set:72157640607666844', }
```

But when I try to set the set number as a variable, it breaks with a "Fatal error: 1 fail: Photoset not found"

```
var fakeVar = 72157640607666844
  Galleria.run('.galleria', {
  flickr: 'set:' + fakeVar, }
```

Any thoughts on how to get this to work?

FYI: I looked at `console.log('set:' + fakeVar)`, and it certainly is returning set:72157640607666844. Initially, I thought it was because it was returning the set without quotes, but I know this is not the case, because if I do `" 'set:"+ fakeVar + " ' "`, I get a no method error for 'set.

Also if it's helpful, this is the Galleria program code that defines the set method:

```
set: function( photoset_id, callback ) {
    return this._find({
        photoset_id: photoset_id,
        method: 'flickr.photosets.getPhotos'
    }, callback);
},
```

Comment: `alert(fakeVar)` – surprise! Use a _string_ value.

Comment: This is an example of things looking like a number but not actually being something you should use a number for in code. If you don't do math with your number you should use a string to represent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`72157640607666844` is too significant of a `Number` for JavaScript to store completely:

```
console.log(72157640607666844);
//          72157640607666850
```

To avoid issues with precision, you can wrap the literal in quotes so it's a `String` instead:

```
var fakeVar = '72157640607666844';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your JavaScript console:

```
alert('set:' + 72157640607666844); alerts "set:72157640607666850" for me
parseInt("72157640607666844") // returns 72157640607666850 for me
```

JavaScript can't deal with numbers this large. It uses double-precision floating-point internally to represent numbers, and 72157640607666850 is as closed to 72157640607666844 as JavaScript can manage. You'll need to leave it in string format or use a  library like [BigNumber](http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber) to deal with this.

Here's [more information on representing Integers](http://www.exploringbinary.com/print-precision-of-floating-point-integers-varies-too/) in a variety of languages.